# Typescript convert type definition into generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For example, type TCmd is defined like below

```
type TCmd = "hello" | "world";
export function foo(cmd: TCmd) {
  let data: Record<TCmd, boolean> = {
    hello: cmd === "hello",
    world: cmd === "world",
  };
  return data;
}
```

Is the inline type generic able to do the same as the one below (incorrect example)? The purpose is to minimize the use of many simple external type definitions, e.g. like "hello"|"world"

```
export function bar<T extends "hello"|"world">(cmd: T) {
  let data: Record<T, boolean> = {
    hello: cmd === "hello", // error
    world: cmd === "world", // error
  };
  return data;
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
Type '{ hello: boolean; world: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, boolean>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hello' does not exist in type 'Record<T, boolean>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is a "tiny but simple external type definition"? What is an "inline generic type"?

Comment: `Record<T, boolean>` or `Record<T, number>`? (hint: `cmd === 'a string'` is not a number)

Comment: Yes I see that but what do they want/expect to happen?

Comment: @caTS I am a newbie to TypeScript.  When more code is developed, I find there are many type definitions required for many functions.  Looking for a way to convert those type definitions into inline generics

Comment: What is an inline generic, though? Is `Record<T, number>` not an inline generic? I'm just not sure what you want.

Comment: @caTS I guess I use the misleading term " inline generic".  What I want to achieve is to minimize the use of type definition, e.g. type TCmd = "hello" | "world", if generic can be used instead.

Comment: But you've done that in your second example. You use `T extends "hello" | "world"` instead of `T extends TCmd`, so I'm still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @caTS the second example causes error, it says Type '{ hello: boolean; world: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, boolean>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hello' does not exist in type 'Record<T, boolean>'.ts(2322)

Comment: Ok, and finally, what do you expect the generic function to return? `Record<T, boolean>`?

Comment: Yes, returned type is Record<T, boolean>.

Comment: But you realize if I call it as `bar("world")`, that'll return the type `{ world: boolean }`?

Comment: But the way I code in the second example causes a compilation error.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1pV2W) work for you? If you reply, please use @caTS to mention me, or else I won't be notified.

Comment: @caTS Thanks for your help.  The playground you provided is able to return the data in Record<T, boolean>. However, the "as Record<T, boolean>" is a kind of type casting.  It loses the checking of T when constructing data, e.g.  let data = { cat: true, dog: true} as Record<T, boolean>.  "cat" and "dog" is not T but no warning will be seen then.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without some sort of cast, either at the definition or when returning.